# ajax and asp classic

Tags: ajax

i'm newbie in programming and i as a marketing executive so i dont know anything about programming  but i very excited to learn programming so now i learn independently.My friend said to me,better for beginner learn C++ first then go to ASP clssic then ASP.NET+PHP+CI..now i in ASP stage.

Question 1 : it is correct suggestion from my friend?

search suggestion

I stack on this problem
how to create live search same as this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

this is my db code

```
Set rsGuestbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT staff_name FROM master WHERE staff_name like '" & Request("s") & "%'"

rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, oConn
```

livesearch.php?q="+str,true = livesearch.php?q="+str,true

please help

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you're only starting out, then don't worry overly about any particular language (unless you have a specific need to learn it). You'd be better off learning the core tenets of programming from a generic tutorial such as:

http://lifehacker.com/#!5401954/programmer-101-teach-yourself-how-to-code

Once you've got a grasp on the basics then try to learn a language suited to your goal. If that's web development then PHP/ASP.NET/RUBY etc. If it's desktop/mobile then look at C/C++/C#/Obj-C/VB.NET according to whatever the platform you are working on needs/offers.

Take a look at W3Schools for web-based languages tuts:

http://www.w3schools.com/

As to the second part of your question, there is so much wrong with your snippet of code on so many levels that I would just put it quietly aside in the cupboard, and re-visit it once you've got a better handle on the basics, and you'll see why it's wrong.

Comment: thank sir..can you give your email for me to send the full code..btw thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Learning C++ is quite 'advanced' and not what I'd recommend for someone who's not studying a computer science degree course or working as a professional programmer.  It's a very big and complex language that requires a lot of other skills,  not least object orientation and general computer science knowledge.

It would be far more appropriate for you to start with something far more simple,  such as classic ASP or PHP.  Choose one only!  Then buy a book.  Then play for a bit.  Then build a simple website about your cat/hamster/car/boat/ear-wax.  Then build another one using the lessons learned from the first website.  I'd suggest looking at several months to hone your skills,  particularly as you're doing it part time.

Learning to program is about as simple as learning to play a musical instrument.  The more you practice the better you get.  Some people are naturally good at it,  but,  alas,  most aren't and have to work very hard.

Answer (score 1):

When your first starting out the language isn't to important (of course go for an easier language). For the most part many of the larger languages are interchangeable (for example a `cout` in C++ is the pretty much the same as a `System.out.print` in JAVA). The more important thing you need to grasp is program structure, Object Oriented Programming principles, and the other basic "do's" and "dont's" of programming. These ideas will apply to just about every programming language you use.

IMO (and this may be wrong) the language you learn is the least important aspect when you are a beginner. Most programmers will have to use many languages in their career and spending the time to learn every in and out of each language would be a waste. For example I started out learning Visual Basic in highschool. After a few months I was switched to C++. Once I went to college I had to learn JAVA for 6 months, then switched to Ruby, then C, CSS, HTML, Android SDK and Javascript. After that I got a job and had to learn C# and how to use AJAX, .Net, facebook API and other languages. Moral of the story is the principles are more important than the languages.

**My advice:** First find out what you want to program. Ira Rainey has some good suggestions as to where to go and what to learn if you look at his answer (though I would include JAVA for a desktop/mobile language)

C++ shouldn't be to advanced if you have the right material to learn it. I would recommend working with C++ to make a few very basic programs. Start by trying to make a basic calculator that will send all input to command line. Once you got the basics down (+,-,*,/) then you can slowly evolve it to be more and more complex (^,%,!). This will give you a platform to build off and a goal to obtain.

[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/) is a site to help you learn C++

Comment: Here's some more for C++: http://www.cprogramming.com/begin.html, http://newdata.box.sk/bx/c/ And for ASP: http://www.learnasp.com/freebook/learn/, http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp